# how to implement windows phone style combobox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, windows-phone

I followed this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392670/custom-combobox-in-wpf-application/24481188#24481188) for creating a flat style combobox. It works fine.

I want to implement the combobox with windows phone type of animation effect.
how can I do it? Can anybody please guild me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make a combobox for your WP8 application, you must install the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/releases/view/107923).

Installation instructions are on their website. You can their [get it from NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/wptoolkit) or [download the source](http://phone.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest).

Once installed, you will have to add the namespace in your xaml:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Then you can create a `ListPicker` like so:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker ItemSource="{Binding YourBindingForList}" />
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I edited this answer to improve it, but now I think the whole answer is not relevant. The question is asking how to implement this effect in WPF. The question is not asking about how to do it in Windows Phone.