# How does a combobox know if your clicking the down arrow or the textbox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a WPF combobox (From the toolbox) that I'm trying to edit.

The created combobox can be filtered by clicking into it and typing what you want.

How does a combobox know (What event gets triggered or element get activated or ...) if your clicking on the arrow or the textbox.

Bonus: Using styles can you change the ratio of the combobox that you can click for the textbox vs the dropdown arrow?

Comment: Not sure why this request was downvoted and closed -- it seems really specific and straightforward, and it even has a valid answer.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 It asks 2 questions, one based on events, and one about display, which will be totally independent, and should be a separate post. You state it has a valid answer, and I don't care about that problem, I'm here for the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `ComboBox` has a default styling which determines the size of the text box and the drop down arrow. Like other controls in WPF, you can edit the control template of the `ComboBox`to change the appearance and size of those items. If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392670/custom-combobox-in-wpf-application) you can see examples of overriding the default styling. What you are interested in is the size of the column definitions:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```